# Flask basic authentication not accepting username and password

Tags: python, flask, basic-authentication

I am using BasicAuth in my flask application on a server. Whenever I try to enter the username and password the app just prompts me again to enter the information and it doesn't authenticate me. I am not sure how to fix this. The code in my app is:

```
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'] = 'user'
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD'] = 'password'

basic_auth = BasicAuth(app)
@app.route("/secret")
@basic_auth.required
def secret_view():
    return submit.html
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to this at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641508/flask-basic-authentication-not-accepting-username-and-password) AWS forum. The problem is with the Elastic Beanstalk configuration: you must configure Apache to pass the authentication headers (i.e., the cleartext username and password from your user) to your python application (and, hence, whatever solution you're using to parse the authentication credentials, in my case `flask_httpauth`) through `mod_wsgi`.

To do this, setup a container command in a `.config` file saved in your `.ebextensions` file. I used the one below.

**.ebextensions/auth.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_wsgi_pass_headers:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

Of course, it goes without saying that since these credentials will be passed as cleartext, **you must set your application to be accessed by, and only by, an HTTPS connection!**

Comment: I encountered the same problem on a standard linux/apache server setup. In that case, another option to resolve is to add "WSGIPassAuthorization On" to the <Directory ...> section of the apache host definition.

Answer (score 0):

This simple example works for me:

> app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.basicauth import BasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'] = 'user'
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD'] = 'password'

basic_auth = BasicAuth(app)
@app.route("/secret")
@basic_auth.required
def secret_view():
    return render_template('secret_page.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> templates/secret_page.html

`Secret page!`

Sample requests:

```
curl -I http://localhost:5000/secret

HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=""
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.8
Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 04:42:42 GMT

curl -I -u user:password http://localhost:5000/secret
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12
Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.8
Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 04:42:54 GMT

curl -u user:password http://localhost:5000/secret
Secret page!
```

Comment: For some reason this works when I am running it on my computer but when I run it on the server the username and password never authenticate and it continues to ask for the credentials.

Comment: Ok, so your code is most likely fine then, and the problem would be a configuration issue with your web server. You should update your question with details of your web server, or ask a new question which focuses on the web server not recognising HTTP Basic Authentication.